Derivative of the multivariate normal cumulative distribution function (CDF) with reparameterisation
I would like to learn how to calculate the derivatives of a multivariate normal cumulative distribution function (MVN CDF) w.r.t. certain elements by using the derivatives of the same MVN CDF w.r.t. the reparameterised elements.
Let $\Phi\left(\textbf{u};0,\mathbf{V}\right)$ be the MVN CDF, where $\textbf{u}$ is a vector of upper limits. As defined below, each $u$ is constructed by one or two random variables $x$. It is noteworhty that the random variable $x_{2}$ is involved in three upper limits $u_{2}$, $u_{3}$ and $u_{4}$.
$$
\textbf{u}=\begin{bmatrix}
u_{1} \\
u_{2} \\
u_{3} \\
u_{4}\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-x_{1} \\
x_{2} \\
x_{2}-x_{3} \\
x_{2}-x_{4}\end{bmatrix}
$$
In the covariance matrix $\mathbf{V}$, each element $v$ is constructed by some random variables $z$.
$$
\mathbf{V} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & v_{12} & v_{13} & v_{14} \\
 & 1 & v_{23} & v_{24} \\
 & & v_{33} & v_{34} \\
 & & & v_{44} \\
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & -f\left(z_{1}\right) & f\left(z_{2}\right)-f\left(z_{1}\right) & f\left(z_{3}\right)-f\left(z_{1}\right) \\
 & 1 & 0.5-f\left(z_{4}\right) & 0.5-f\left(z_{5}\right) \\
 & & 1-2f\left(z_{4}\right) & 0.5-f\left(z_{4}\right)-f\left(z_{5}\right)+f\left(z_{6}\right) \\
 & & & 1-2f\left(z_{5}\right) \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
f\left(z_{k}\right) = \frac{tanh\left(z_{k}\right)}{2}\begin{matrix}, & k=1,2,...6 \\
\end{matrix}
$$
Suppose that we already know the following first-order derivatives by certain computer programmes, e.g. the GHK simulator.
$$
\frac{\partial\Phi\left(\textbf{u};0,\mathbf{V}\right)}{\partial\mathbf{u}} = \begin{bmatrix}
g\left(u_{1}\right) \\
g\left(u_{2}\right) \\
g\left(u_{3}\right) \\
g\left(u_{4}\right)\end{bmatrix} 
$$
$$
\frac{\partial\Phi\left(\textbf{u};0,\mathbf{V}\right)}{\partial\mathbf{V}}  = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & g\left(v_{12}\right) & g\left(v_{13}\right) & g\left(v_{14}\right) \\
 & 1 & g\left(v_{23}\right) & g\left(v_{24}\right) \\
 & & g\left(v_{33}\right) & g\left(v_{34}\right) \\
 & & & g\left(v_{34}\right) \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
The reason I previously used both $u$ and $x$ to define $\mathbf{u}$ and used both $v$ and $z$ to define $\mathbf{V}$ is to distinguish what is known from what is unknown. For example, the computer programme can give us $g\left(u_{2}\right)$ but not $g\left(x_{2}\right)$, even if $u_{2}=x_{2}$ by definition. (Note that $x_{2}$ is involved in not only $u_{2}$ but also $u_{3}$ and $u_{4}$.)
I would like to whether it is possible to calculate the derivatives w.r.t. $x$ and $z$ using the above data; if yes, then how? For example, do the following equations hold?
$$
\frac{\partial\Phi\left(\textbf{u};0,\mathbf{V}\right)}{\partial x_{1}} = -g\left(u_{1}\right)
$$
$$
\frac{\partial\Phi\left(\textbf{u};0,\mathbf{V}\right)}{\partial x_{2}} = g\left(u_{2}\right)+g\left(u_{3}\right)+g\left(u_{4}\right)
$$
$$
\frac{\partial\Phi\left(\textbf{u};0,\mathbf{V}\right)}{\partial x_{3}} = -g\left(u_{3}\right)
$$
$$
\frac{\partial\Phi\left(\textbf{u};0,\mathbf{V}\right)}{\partial x_{4}} = -g\left(u_{4}\right)
$$
Moreover, how about the derivatives w.r.t. $z$ ?
$$
\frac{\partial\Phi\left(\textbf{u};0,\mathbf{V}\right)}{\partial z_{1}} = \begin{matrix} ? & \\ \end{matrix}
\frac{\partial\Phi\left(\textbf{u};0,\mathbf{V}\right)}{\partial z_{2}} = \begin{matrix} ? & \\ \end{matrix}
\frac{\partial\Phi\left(\textbf{u};0,\mathbf{V}\right)}{\partial z_{3}} = \begin{matrix} ? & \\ \end{matrix}
$$
$$
\frac{\partial\Phi\left(\textbf{u};0,\mathbf{V}\right)}{\partial z_{4}} = \begin{matrix} ? & \\ \end{matrix}
\frac{\partial\Phi\left(\textbf{u};0,\mathbf{V}\right)}{\partial z_{5}} = \begin{matrix} ? & \\ \end{matrix}
\frac{\partial\Phi\left(\textbf{u};0,\mathbf{V}\right)}{\partial z_{6}} = \begin{matrix} ? & \\ \end{matrix}
$$
For example, I have tried the following equation, but that doesn't seem right:
$$
\frac{\partial\Phi\left(\textbf{u};0,\mathbf{V}\right)}{\partial z_{1}} = \frac{-g\left(v_{12}\right)-g\left(v_{13}\right)-g\left(v_{14}\right)}{2cosh\left(z_{1}\right)^{2}}
$$
Please let me know if more information is needed. Thank you very much.

Plenty of your notations need be defined. What are the observations and the parameters involved in the likelihood?

Sorry for the confusion. Perhaps I shouldn't mention MLE at all. Although I am doing MLE, my question is more about calculus, so I framed my questions with simpler notations, in order to reduce complexity. Once someone kindly helps me to resolve my questions (i.e., how to use the derivatives w.r.t. u and v to calculate the derivatives w.r.t. x and z), I will apply the answer to my MLE programme with necessary adaptation. The post has been edited to avoid confusion. Thank you.

I agree that the notation needs clarification: there's a proliferation of unexplained variables that have no evident need to appear at all--the $x_i$ in particular--and there's no reason generally to suppose that the derivatives have the particularly simple forms ascribed to them.  Readers will not be inclined to work on any answers if they cannot be reasonably sure they are interpreting the question as intended.

Thank you for the advice. I've added more information in the post. Especially, I explain why I use both u and x to define the upper limit vector. I also edited the post to point out that I am not assuming the derivatives must have simple forms; instead, I am asking whether it is possible to use the derivatives w.r.t. u and v to calculate the derivatives w.r.t. x and z; in case it is possible, then I would like to learn how to do that. Please let me know if more information is needed. Thanks.

The short answer is apply the Chain Rule.  Check out the Wikipedia article for instance or consult a textbook on multivariable Calculus.
